# Sphinx document generator search not working

Tags: python, full-text-search, python-sphinx

I am creating a document with the SPHINX document generator. I have added many entries to the document successfully. My problem is searching for these entires. When I search for a word that should get 1 or more hits, it doesn't get enough. Do I need to set something up for search to work?

[image: page]

The above image is what my results page looks like after searching for list. There are many entires in the document that use the word list , yet only one result appears in the results page.

Comment: Could you provide access to the source files, for example on GitHub?

Comment: Hi, after looking into it a little more, i discovered that there was nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with version 1.5.1. Update to the latest version (pip install -U Sphinx on Linux) and the search will work again.